# How to translate a 'greeting_for' function from Ruby to Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby

Here's a sample code:

```
def greeting_for(name)
  "Hello, #{name}!"
end

puts greeting_for "Marty"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+hello+name

Comment: _"i've been stuck on this"_ – what have you tried so far? What problem(s) are you facing?

Comment: What do you mean by stuck? Do you understand your code at all? Take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for more information on how to ask a question.

Comment: "Any help would be appreciated." – Help with *what*? What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve]. [so] is not a "write-my-code-for-me-service"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be translated to JavaScript as:

```
function greeting_for (name) {
  return `Hello, ${name}!`
}

console.log( greeting_for( "Marty" ) )
```

Comment: thats what i ended up doing. Sorry for the random question. I'm new to coding and working on HW.

Comment: You're welcome. Make sure you read the links that other programmers pointed out, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by your question. But, it sounds like you want to create a string that puts your variable inside it (in this case a greeting)and print it to the screen/console/wherever using Javascript.

You could create a function like below:

```
const greeting_for = function(name){       
    return `Hello, ${name}!`
};
```

And then call it like so:

```
greeting_for("Mary");
```

If you did this inside your chrome dev tools under console it would return:

> "Hello, Mary!"

With more info we could provide a more thorough answer.